# how to get value using get method from php

Tags: php, parameters, get

below is url : http://test.com/admin.php?&state=JAMMU+&KASHMIR

using get method i want value of parameter state.

thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code

```
echo $_GET['state'];
```

Update:

To get `&` as a value in GET variable it first need to be encoded i.e.,
The url would be

```
'https://www.test.com/admin.php?&state='.urlencode('JAMMU+&KASHMIR')

echo urldecode($_GET['state']);
```

Comment: i want whole value of state

Comment: It will give you value for get variable `state`

Comment: no it will give only value jammu while i need jammu_&kashmir

Comment: For that you will have to first encode the character `&` before passing it on the url and then on the other side it will need to be decoded

Answer (score 1):

If you are generating the URL through some php script then you should use urldecode() php function to encode the state value.
like thee bolow code

```
<a href="https://www.test.com/admin.php?&state=<?php echo urlencode('JAMMU+&KASHMIR'); ?>">click me</a>
```

**or simply change the ULR to**

```
http://test.com/admin.php?&state=JAMMU+%26KASHMIR
```

this will resolve your issue.